# How to fix "Database error: The frontend does not match Zabbix database."

Tags: database, zabbix

I have a problem with *Zabbix*:

> Database error:
>
> The frontend does not match Zabbix database. Current database version (mandatory/optional): 0/0. Required mandatory version: 2020000. Contact your system administrator.

Comment: 2020000 means you are installing Zabbix version 2, when latest is (currently) 4.2.5?

Comment: Yes i have version 2.

Comment: So you upgrading from 2.0 to 2.2? Did you already check the docs? https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/installation/upgrade

Comment: I dont upgrading to 2.2, i have flooded server and i try to restore my server from backup. Everything works except Zabbix.

Comment: How did you backup Zabbix database, and how did you restore it?

Comment: When i go to: "nano /var/log/zabbixsrv/zabbix_server.log" i got this:


 18771:20190912:100911.624 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix_server.conf
 18771:20190912:100911.634 [Z3005] query failed: [1286] Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' [select mandatory,optional from dbversion]
 18771:20190912:100911.635 Cannot get the database version. Exiting ...
 28727:20190912:103930.355 Starting Zabbix Server. Zabbix 2.2.11 (revision 56693).

Comment: can you query the DB directly using `myqsl` from command line? is the mysql service running? are there errors in the mysql log?