# i received an zabbix server start error and shared solition

Tags: zabbix

I recieved an error. It is in  /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log

> [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2059] Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>     3020:20191216:145338.629 Cannot connect to the database. Exiting...

And i can't start zabbix-server

```
service zabbix-server start
```

or

```
systemctl start zabbix-server
```

i want to show status with `systemctl status zabbix-server` command

The output was as pictured
[image: zabbix-server start fail]

this solition is in answer.

Comment: [First look here for solitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249895/how-to-fix-database-error-the-frontend-does-not-match-zabbix-database) If you delete default users. You get this error.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem by changing the password authentication method to `mysql_native_password` as following.

```
[root@localhost ~] # mysql -u root -p
Enter password: <enter MySql root user's password when prompted>

mysql> alter user 'zabbix'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'YOUR-NEW_PASSWORD-HERE';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  grant all privileges on zabbix.* to 'zabbix'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> quit;
Bye
```